# How can testability help in identifying and fixing bugs before they are integrated into the system?

Tags: integration, bug-report, system

Loose coupling promotes testability because it allows components to be tested in isolation without having to test the entire system. This can help to reduce the risk of introducing new bugs by making it easier to identify and fix bugs before they are integrated into the system.

How can testability help in identifying and fixing bugs before they are integrated into the system?

Comment: Where are you getting that statement from? the context is probably important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can testability help in identifying and fixing bugs before they are integrated into the system?

I can see two potential reasons for your confusion.

**First**
Implementing `Testability` (something which can be tested) in of itself won't help in identifying and fixing bugs. Just because you loosely couple your objects and follow the proposed pattern, it won't help you directly unless you implement testing into the process of writing code.

**Second**
Implementing `Testability` on a macro scale won't help **much** in identifying and fixing bugs before they are integrated into the system. Tests need to be written and vetted at all scales from micro (static method) to macro (application testing).

If you write your tests before: writing your static method; writing your class; integrating your service or ... than you'll be able to catch more bugs that live at this scale, and you'll have a better idea as to what is causing a  bug because you'll have more confidence that the issue isn't related to lower levels of your code.

## Theoretical Example.

You are building a calculator from scratch.

A button you want to integrate into your calculator computes `(x^2+x^3-x^x)/(x-x^2+3)/ArcCos(x-x^2+pi) mod 3`. There are multiple values of x where your application will cause an error and writing a test to test all possible x's is inefficient and likely to miss specific cases.

By loosely coupling and writing tests for each method used (Product, Addition, Power, ArcCos, Mod and Division) you'll be able to see which inputs will cause exceptions for which inputs.

By writing tests for each level of your component you'll quickly see where issues will arise and you'll be better situated to handle them.

Comprehensive Tests for `a/b` will show an error when `b=0` which you can handle as you see fit. How you choose to handle this mean that when `(x-x^2+3) = 0` and your test for the component fails, you should be in a much more knowledgeable position to **identify and fix the bug before you integrate the component into the calculator.

Comment: Nice example, that demonstrates flaws of Unit testing. If operations are tested in isolation, a bug in order of operations will go unnoticed.

Comment: @Basilevs except that isn't a flaw with [Unit Tests](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923). That's a flaw with [Solitary Tests](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html).

Comment: Even with sociable test, if you follow test pyramid and reduce the test count for expression calculation (because that is a more of an integration test), you will have the same problem,

Comment: Meanwhile, system tests for an calculator are orders of magnitude easier to write than unit tests.

Comment: @Basilevs Sure, writing crapy tests is easier. But reliable tests are easier to use. Whose time are you going to respect?

Answer (score 1):

> Loose coupling promotes testability because it allows components to be tested in isolation without having to test the entire system.

Coupling comes in [many forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). Testability usually flows from the forms that allow a behavior to have more than one driver. Specifically a test, in addition to operational code.  Only forms that permit that promote testability. More is needed here than simply loose coupling.

> This can help to reduce the risk of introducing new bugs by making it easier to identify and fix bugs before they are integrated into the system.

Integrating a bug is no sin. What matters is when code is made testable. The longer that takes the harder it is to make it testable. Some bugs can't be detected until they are integrated because they are integration bugs. Integration tests are good tests. They exist for a reason. The sin is letting the bug live long. [The longer a bug lives](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/322260/131624) the more expensive it is to fix.

> How can testability help in identifying and fixing bugs before they are integrated into the system?

By making it easy to write tests. When you say testability while excluding integration tests you are likely thinking of [unit tests](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/400277/131624). To achieve testability of the code for the sake of unit tests you need more than loose coupling. You need a unit boundary (which doesn't have to be only one class) that provides an API (interface) that lets a test elicit a behavior from the code under test (in the unit).

That should be deterministic (always does the same thing), parallelizable (can be run while other tests run), and fast (so you can run it as often as you type a semicolon). To do that the unit must be free of IO code. No database, network, or filesystem interaction. No peripherals at all. That is important to unit testing but has nothing to do with loose coupling. That requires you to arrange the code in the unit so that IO can be isolated from the unit test.

A pattern that lets you write such code is called [functional core](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/functional-core-imperative-shell). This works by pushing IO up the call stack to an outer layer where IO code lives closer to configuration code. This makes using the IO a choice rather than a requirement. That permits isolating the behavior code from it's needed IO so the unit test can avoid IO. This isn't simply loose coupling. This is consciously following a unit testable design.

But if the bug is that the DB connection string is wrong then none of that helps. Integration tests are still important. They are just the wrong tools to exercise the units behaviors. They are the perfect tests to figure out if you plugged things together the right way.

Answer (score 1):

What do we mean by "testability"?

Presumably we mean a form that is amenable to automatic tests.

**Interfaces**

For automatic tests, there typically have to be additional internal interfaces, beyond that required for ordinary operation. The purpose of these additional interfaces is to allow parts to be detached from the whole, and preset inputs provided and outputs measured. Sometimes they might also allow the parts to be hooked into whilst in normal use, or will automatically divert information out for logging, analysis, and alerting.

Other branches of engineering also understand this technique. They have their gas sampling ports and electrical test points, and their flanges and connectors to allow parts to be completely dismantled from a larger apparatus.

**Manual tests**

But I'd also suggest that amenability to *manual* tests is closely related to amenability to automatic tests.

It's very difficult to examine and test things even by hand, without there being internal interfaces.

When manually testing, it may be possible to carve out the code, or apply a step-through debugger, but testing and debugging is made rather more difficult when there are not built-in interfaces included in the code for the purpose, which can be hooked into simply.

Nobody would gladly have a car engine that requires dismantling just to dip the oil or check the water. And the car shouldn't have to be moving at speed to check the spark plugs or apply a stethoscope to the engine - because testing under such circumstances is difficult and risks wider harm in the process.

So code that is "testable" from an automatic perspective, is also one that has good facilities for manual testing.

**Manual analysis**

And finally, I'd mention "manual analysis" as a form of testing. This is about reasoning mentally about how the code will execute, in order to examine and verify the correctness of the process.

What facilitates manual analysis is when all the necessary information to do so is easily available, and when the scale of the analysis is as small and local as possible. We "structure" code for this purpose.

Properly structured code either has interfaces by default (as part of the intrinsic organisation that was already necessary for the programmer to write the logic correctly and remain able to read and analyse it), or it is most of the way there and easily accommodates the insertion of additional interfaces.

That is, you can be looking at a wall of text in a single overly-long method (a la 1975, when method calls were still thought to be computationally expensive), but if it is written to a professional standard and is therefore properly structured internally, then it will almost certainly decompose into separate methods without much upset.

**Conclusion**

In my view "testability" is almost inextricable from competently-written code. The ability to correctly create and analyse code depends on its good structuring, and with structure you either get interfaces as part of the structuring, or you get natural places for extra interfaces to be inserted for testing.

Answer (score 0):

> How can testability help in identifying and fixing bugs

On it's own it doesn't. You have to have tests, and run them. It being easy to write tests doesn't cause tests to spontaneously appear.

It being easy to write tests means that the cost of writing tests is low, which means they have a better return on investment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference to pre-integration regression testing with unit tests in CI.

## Feature testing

If all regression tests pass on every feature branch before it is merged, no regressions can reach the main branch, detected bugs are easier to isolate (as independent features under development do not interfere with each other).
[This works with manual testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/45048/feature-branch-testing-before-code-is-merged), but requires significant human effort.

## Continuous integration

With automated regression tests and an [infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102386/with-continuous-integration-why-are-tests-run-after-committing-instead-of-befor) to test multiple branches independently, the cost of pre-integration testing is significantly reduced, without losing benefits.

Advocates of [Continuous Delivery](https://continuousdelivery.com/foundations/continuous-integration/) argue that passing automated tests is the only precondition for merge.

## Unit tests

[Test Pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html#TheTestPyramid) states that unit tests are easier to develop and are preferred over integration and system tests. They are also fast to execute and are more likely to be run.

## Conclusion

Combining the above axioms, one concludes that loose coupling makes unit tests easier, enables pre-integration testing and protects the main branch for regressions.

## Objection

This conclusion is in general incorrect, as it is based on invalid assumptions:

- Unit tests are [neither easier to write than system tests nor do they reveal more bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/452347/how-can-testability-help-in-identifying-and-fixing-bugs-before-they-are-integrat). They localize a bug much better, but this is not relevant for pre-integration testing, where bugs are already fairly localized.
- Benefits of pre-integration testing are achievable with any kind of testing including manual tests.
- Unit tests are indeed fast. But this is irrelevant for automated regression testing; modern tools can run as many background regression jobs as necessary and do not consume time or attention of a developer.

A more accurate conclusion is: testing features before merge into master prevents bugs in master. This is a trivial statement and has no practical implication besides the usual tradeoff - the more effort spent on each feature, the fewer bugs it introduces.

Comment: This is in part a troll-post.

Answer (score 0):

I cant find the source of your statement, but the phrase "fix bugs before they are integrated into the system" comes up in lots of exams where they are talking about **Unit Testing**. Specifically unit testing components which are later used together to make a system.

So if we restate your question with this replacement:

> How can testability (of my component) help in (making unit tests) so that (I can test it before its used in a bigger system)

The answer becomes obvious. If your component is hard to test, due to tight coupling, it's hard to write unit tests. Which in turn mean you won't find bugs in your component, before its "integrated into the system"